# Video cannot be processed error notification while uploading a video

Tags: android, facebook, video, upload, video-processing

when i try to upload a video of different formats(including .mp4 and .3gp files) to facebook from my android application, i get a notification in my facebook account saying 'Your video could not be processed.visit the video help page to learn about the common problems'. Please help me on this.
postToWall function post the video to facebook.

```
    private void postToWall(String accessToken) {        
         String dataPath = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/video-2013-04-11-04-30-05.mp4";
         InputStream is = null;
         byte[] data = null;
         try {
            is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
            data = readBytes(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Bundle params = new Bundle();   
        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());              
        params.putString("filename", "Video_02.mp4");
        params.putByteArray("video", data);
        params.putString("contentType", "video/quicktime");
       params.putString("message", "video message");         
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", params, "POST", new PostRequestListener(), null);
    }


               public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // This dynamically extends to take the bytes you read.
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // This is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes.
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // We need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer.
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // And then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Same issue under iOS too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522857/sharing-video-on-facebook-fails I am staring to think that this is a bug on Facebook side.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a new known bug of the Facebook API or SDK (first report today).

You can back the bug report here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/543903808965945