# Sharing video on Facebook fails

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6

I am sharing a video on Facebook using Facebook SDK 3.1.1. I have mentioned the code here.

```
FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // for each fbid in the array, we create a request object to fetch
    // the profile, along with a handler to respond to the results of the request
    NSString *fbid = @"me";
    // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
    FBRequestHandler handler =
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        // output the results of the request
        [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:fbid result:result error:error];
    };

    // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path
    // as an alternative the request* static methods of the FBRequest class could
    // be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                                   @"hello",@"subdescription",
                                   nil];
    FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:theDelegate.session graphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/?fields=location"];

    // add the request to the connection object, if more than one request is added
    // the connection object will compose the requests as a batch request; whether or
    // not the request is a batch or a singleton, the handler behavior is the same,
    // allowing the application to be dynamic in regards to whether a single or multiple
    // requests are occuring
    [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

    // if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
    [self.requestConnection cancel];

    // keep track of our connection, and start it
    self.requestConnection = newConnection;
    [newConnection start];
```

It was working properly earlier. I get the shared Video Id in response every time I initiate an upload video request. But I keep getting the following message when I check my profile on FB in the notifications.

> Your Video could not be processed. Visit the Video help page to learn about common problems

I have tried this with different AppIds. Uploading video is working though when I upload it using Facebook website.

Comment: have you checked with the older facebook SDKs

Comment: yes I have. facing the same issue with that too.

Comment: yes it is urgent. I am doing from my iOS app. I have to submit it to AppStore with this feature included.

Comment: Same issue under Android (13 hours ago)… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518434/video-cannot-be-processed-error-notification-while-uploading-a-video I'm starting to think this is a Facebook bug.

Comment: Same problem for me under iOS, with an older version of Fb SDK. My code used to be working before (yesterday) and now this feature seems to be broken… :-/

Comment: have you tried with the new SDK

Comment: ya I am facing the same problem with the old as well as new facebook sdk (3.1.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working now :) 
you can check at
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/543903808965945

Comment: Yes, as of last night (March 21st 22:00 GMT 2013) it seems to work again. Let's hope it contines like this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a new known Facebook bug (first report today).

You can back the bug report here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/543903808965945